# Пошаговость, варианты реализации

Tags: python, pygame

У меня есть несколько классов персонажей реализованных на pygame, я бы хотел сделать так. чтобы в случае боя, они атаковали последовательно (атаковал противник, потом я выбрал что сделать и, например, атаковал), как в любой другой игре с пошаговым боем. Никак не могу понять, как это можно сделать не городя условия.
Просто так они работать не будут, т.к в pygame цикл событий обрабатывается параллельно с отрисовкой и остальным.

Comment: Возможно есть какой-то класс (может быть и самописный), чтобы использовать его как модуль для таких вещей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что там городить-то? Сделайте переменную для того, чей сейчас ход, например, `current_team = "player"`, потом перед действием игрока проверяйте, что ход его, и если так, то выполняйте действие и меняйте переменную. В цикле событий отслеживайте, когда ход даётся противнику, там аналогично, он действует и возвращает ход игроку. Без понимания таких элементарных алгоритмов в разрабатывать игры никак (:

Я с `pygame` не работал, но должно быть примерно так:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode()

PLAYER = 'player'
ENEMY = 'enemy'
team = PLAYER

while True:
    # ... отрисовка ...

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        if team != PLAYER:
            break
        # Отслеживаем действия игрока
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_0:
                pass
                # И после какого-нибудь действия меняем ход
                team = PLAYER
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            pass

    if team == ENEMY:
        # Для красоты сюда можно поставить какую-нибудь задержку или что угодно согласно дизайну

        # ... ход противника ... 
        # Смена хода
        team = PLAYER
```

Comment: Хах, я и не подумал ломать ивент-луп. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Специально для того, чтобы не городить условия, для таких случаев были придуманы **Конечные автоматы (FSM — Finite-state machine)**, которые имеют [ряд преимуществ](http://gameinstitute.ru/tutorials/state-driven_agents/) при проектировании игровых решений.